# Change UISegmentedControl text

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to change the text of UISegmentedControl I made in IB. This is the code

```
[changeButton removeAllSegments];
[changeButton insertSegmentWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Traffic",@"traffic string")  atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[changeButton insertSegmentWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Satellite",@"satellite string")  atIndex:1 animated:YES];
```

But nothing happens: I see always the default label IB put for me ("First" and "Second").
For sure, I put the IBOUtlet in my .h:

```
 __weak IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *changeButton;
```

What am I missing? In general, when I create a control in IB, in order to access it programmatically, putting an IBOutlet into the .h is the correct way?

Comment: You are mixing up properties and ivars. Is changeButton a property?

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't think that what OP has is a property declaration, by the way it doesn't matter here if it's a weak property or a weak variable.

Comment: It does matter though if he's connecting the property changeButton and trying to access the ivar changeButton. They are not the same thing. He will need to access the ivar _changeButton (or self.changeButton).

Comment: @Fogmeister They are not the same thing, but they point to the same object (their value is the same), whether the property or the ivar is accessed. OP doesn't try to set the property itself, but properties of the segmented control.

Comment: No, if you set a property called button and an ivar called button. The synthesise (if not over written) will set the property button to an iVar of _button. _button and button are not pointing to the same thing. If you link the property button in Interface Builder then the ivar button will be nil. In fact, you actually get a warning if you create a property and ivar of the same name. The warning tells you that they will not point to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
The problem is that I wrote the above instructions in the init method. They should go inside the viewDidLoad method instead!

Answer (score 1):

```
__weak
```

Oh wait... if it's weak, it's deallocated and nulled at end of scope (when the method that creates it returns). Omit that `__weak` and it should be fine.

Comment: Does not work. I deleted __weak...and the result is the same.

Comment: @giuseppe I will keep this answer as a reference who actually make this mistake. Doing what I advised is also necessary (apart from moving the code from `init` to `viewDidLoad`). By the way, if you created the UI elements using code (as opposed to using IB), you could safely change their properties in `init` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is only relevant if you are setting both a property and an ivar called changeButton. It isn't clear from the OP so putting this here just in case.

Looks like you are mixing properties and ivars.

changeButton ivar is not the same as the property changeButton.

Delete the line...

```
 __weak IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *changeButton;
```

from the .h

and change the code to...

```
[_changeButton removeAllSegments];
[_changeButton insertSegmentWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Traffic",@"traffic string")  atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[_changeButton insertSegmentWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Satellite",@"satellite string")  atIndex:1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't understand: if I put  "if (changeButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)", I can access changeButton. Why should I use _changeButton?

Comment: Like I said, this is only relevant if you have set up both a property and an ivar for changeButton. It is possible to send messages to nil so changeButton.selectSegmentIndex will work even if changeButton is nil. Set a break point (or NSLog) to check if changeButton is nil.

Comment: Yes, it is nil. Why? In my .h I have only "IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *changeButton;". No other definition. Anyway, if I delete the line __weak, the build fails, there is no reference to _changeButton.